# Use (Linux) virtualenv from Windows

Tags: python, django, windows, virtualenv, shared-directory

I want to develop a Python application on Windows 7, by using a Linux VM. I would like to make use of the Python interpreter that's inside my VM (virtualenv).

Unfortunately, PyCharm is the only editor that supports the use of a remote interpreter. Is it possible to make use of my virtualenv when using Komodo IDE for instance, without installing local (Windows) libraries?

I have tried VirtualBox shared folders, VMWare shared folders and ExpanDrive, but they all seem a little unstable for this purpose (random operation not permitted errors when creating virtualenv in a shared folder).

Thanks in advance

EDIT: To be specific, I need the site-packages from the virtualenv. When I pip install an app like Django, I would like my IDE to auto-complete imports etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ssh into the vm.
Honestly I think the best solution would be to just fullscreen the vm and do it all in there, but that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

Virtualenv on Linux uses `bash` scripts. These won't work on Windows. The Windows version of virtualenv uses either batch files or the PowerShell. They won't work on Linux. One solution that may work would be to setup the same virtualenv on both Linux and Windows. That is, you have to install all packages twice: once on Linux and once on Windows. Putting your own code on a shared drive should work, unless there are some problems I have not anticipated. ;)